# recv()-ing a String with "\0" and "\n" in it

Tags: c, network-programming, printf

So coded a client which is recieving only chars in the Buffer which I print out afterwards:

```
//CODE FROM BJ'S GUIDE TO NETWORK PROGRAMMING *1
if ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("recv");
        exit(1);
    }

    buf[numbytes] = '\0';

    printf("%s",buf);
//MY CODE
    while (numbytes > 0) {
        numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE-1, 0);
        if (numbytes > 0) {
            buf[numbytes] = '\0';
            printf("\%s",buf);
        }
    }
```

buf is a char[512]-array

I want to also recv() "\0" and "\n" and print them out as "\0" and "\n"

as code this would look like this

```
printf("this contains a \\n byte and a \\0 byte");
```

I cannot change something server-sided because So i have to edit the recieving side

*1: https://beej.us/guide/bgnet/

Comment: If the buffer can contain multiple `\0` bytes, it's not a string and you can't just use string functions. You will have to treat it like a memory buffer and process it using the `numbytes` variable. One way is to just read it one char at a time and output that char literally if possible, or escape it if desired.

Comment: You can use `memchr()` to look for `'\0'` value bytes.

Comment: `recv` doesn't give you a null-terminated string.  It gives you a buffer of bytes, and a separate count, telling you how many bytes there are.  Since it's not a string, you can't print it with normal C string-handling functions, like `printf` `%s`.  You could print it to the screen using `fwrite(buf, 1, numbytes, stdout);`.

Comment: In your context, 'numbytes' is not assigned any value prior to entering the loop. What if it is initially greater than 0? Why don't insert recv() in while () expression as Beej does? And also recv() does not return a string as mentioned above. You shouldn't replace the last received byte with '\0'.

Comment: while ((numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE, 0) > 0) {

Comment: so you wanna say you do not have a clue about yeah?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok we did it by using `fwrite()` like this

```
    fwrite(buf, numbytes, sizeof(char), stdout);
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to also recv() "\0" and "\n" and print them out as "\0" and "\n"

Do not use *string* functions on `buf`.  Handle it as an array of characters.

```
while (numbytes > 0) {
  numbytes = recv(sockfd, buf, MAXDATASIZE, 0);
  for (i = 0; i < numbytes; i++) {
    unsigned char ch = buf[numbytes];
    if (ch <= '\n') {  // Escape characters 0 to 13
      putc('\\');
      putc("0123456abtrvfn"[ch]);
    } else if (ch == '\\') {  // I suspect OP will also want this
      putc('\\');
      putc('\\');
    } else {
      putc(ch); 
    }
  }
}
```